# Is there a list of mobile browsers which I must support and test for?

Tags: css, xhtml, windows-mobile, mobile-safari

Is there a list of mobile browsers which I must support and test for?

There are so many mobile devices and browser, it may not be possible to test for all and support all.

Yahoo made a list for Desktop browsers http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/gbs/

Does anyone knows any suggested browsers list [like this](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/gbs/) for Mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

It's up to you what devices you want to support. But probably, depending on what you do, you should look into some sort of 3rd party lib to help you. Maybe you'll be interested in [DeviceAtlas](http://deviceatlas.com/) or [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net has browser capability detection built in via the `System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities` class. [MSDN did a decent write up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300549.aspx) a while back on how to use it.

The [Mobile Device Browser File](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/) is an updated data file on Codeplex for the browser capabilities subsystem with profiles for tons of new mobile devices.

While the MDBF is a giant XML file, it will tell you not only what mobile devices .net is aware of, but their capabilities too.